# How can I combine two SQL queries returning multiple columns into separate columns of the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to combine the following SQL queries to return a single table with the column names:

mnth, correct_predictions, incorrect_predictions

ts is a timestamp type.

```
SELECT monthname(ts) as mnth, count(*) AS correct_predictions
FROM prediction 
WHERE actual = 1 AND result = 1 OR actual = 0 AND result = 0
GROUP BY monthname(ts);

SELECT monthname(ts) as mnth, count(*) AS incorrect_predictions
FROM prediction 
WHERE actual = 0 AND result = 1 OR actual = 1 AND result = 0
GROUP BY monthname(ts);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MySQL treats booleans as 1 or 0 in a numeric context, you can just `SUM` the result of comparing `actual` and `result` to get your required columns:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(ts) as mnth, 
       SUM(actual = result) AS correct_predictions,
       SUM(actual != result) AS incorrect_predictions
FROM prediction 
GROUP BY mnth;
```

Note that using `MONTHNAME` will result in values from every year being grouped together (e.g. May 2019 with May 2020). That may be what you want (or perhaps you are restricting the range of the query with a `WHERE` clause) but if not, you should use something like

```
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM ts) AS mnth
```

to include the year in the value you are grouping by.

Comment: @mrrain . . . This is actually much simpler.  I would, however, advise you to include the year as well as the month name in the `select` and `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff good point about the year, I've made a note about it in the answer.

Comment: @Nick very neat solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with `case`

```
SELECT 
    monthname(ts) as mnth,
    sum(case
            when (actual = 1 AND result = 1) OR (actual = 0 AND result = 0) then 1 else 0 
        end) 
   AS correct_predictions,
    sum(case
            when (actual = 0 AND result = 1) OR (actual = 1 AND result = 0) then 1 else 0 
        end) 
   AS incorrect_predictions
FROM prediction 
GROUP BY monthname(ts);
```